# OpenStack Swift + Keystone: Unable to determine tenancy

Tags: python, openstack-swift, keystone

I'm trying to access Swift with curl using Keystone-based authentication (following the [Keystone API docs here](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/keystone/index.html)).

#### Chapter 1: Fetching the token:

```
curl -d '{"auth": {"passwordCredentials": {
                     "username": "USERNAME", "password": "PASSWORD"}}}' \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     http://identity:35357/v2.0/tokens
```

Response:

```
{
  "access": {
    "token": {
      "expires": "2014-02-27T11:35:11Z", 
      "id": "TOKENID"
    }, 
    "serviceCatalog": [], 
    "user": {
      "username": "USERNAME", 
      "roles_links": [], 
      "id": "USERID", 
      "roles": [], 
      "name": "NAME"
    }
   }
}
```

Note that, contrary to what's said in the [API docs](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/keystone/api_curl_examples.html#id3), the tenant info is missing from the response.

---

#### Chapter 2: Authentication

```
curl -H "X-Auth-Token: TOKENID" http://swift/v1/AUTH_TENANTID/bucket
```

Response: `401 Unauthorized`

---

#### Chapter 3: Troubleshooting

After looking inside the Keystone auth_token middleware, I found that it fails when trying to fetch the tenant from the token data:

```
def get_tenant_info():
    """Returns a (tenant_id, tenant_name) tuple from context."""
    def essex():
        """Essex puts the tenant ID and name on the token."""
        return (token['tenant']['id'], token['tenant']['name'])

    def pre_diablo():
        """Pre-diablo, Keystone only provided tenantId."""
         return (token['tenantId'], token['tenantId'])

    def default_tenant():
        """Pre-grizzly, assume the user's default tenant."""
        return (user['tenantId'], user['tenantName'])

    for method in [essex, pre_diablo, default_tenant]:
        try:
            return method()
        except KeyError:
             pass

    raise InvalidUserToken('Unable to determine tenancy.')
```

Since there is no tenant info in the token data, it always fails.
What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer addresses your initial authentication question, but not the rest of the question...

Your initial request:

```
curl -d '{"auth": {"passwordCredentials": {
                     "username": "USERNAME", "password": "PASSWORD"}}}' \
     -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
     http://identity:35357/v2.0/tokens
```

Needs to provide either a `tenantName` or `tenantId` attribute.  With either of these supplied, your reply should include both the tenant information *and* a service catalog, for looking up other service endpoints.

So:

```
curl -d '{"auth": {"tenantName": "mytenant", "passwordCredentials": {
                         "username": "USERNAME", "password": "PASSWORD"}}}' \
         -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
         http://identity:35357/v2.0/tokens
```

Which should get you something like this:

```
{
  "access": {
    "metadata": {
      "roles": [
        "9fe2ff9ee4384b1894a90878d3e92bab",
        "0ecb6fccfd8546148cbb00b6d51364ce"
      ],
      "is_admin": 0
    },
    "user": {
      "name": "lars",
      "roles": [
        {
          "name": "_member_"
        },
        {
          "name": "admin"
        }
      ],
      "id": "436d522125584cf3a21ddcf628d59e2e",
      "roles_links": [],
      "username": "lars"
    },
    "serviceCatalog": [
      {
        "name": "nova",
        "type": "compute",
        "endpoints_links": [],
        "endpoints": [
          {
            "publicURL": "http://192.168.200.1:8774/v2/28a490a259974817b88ce490a74df8d2",
            "id": "264f2b4179ca4d6ca3a62b7347db11ce",
            "internalURL": "http://192.168.200.1:8774/v2/28a490a259974817b88ce490a74df8d2",
            "region": "RegionOne",
            "adminURL": "http://192.168.200.1:8774/v2/28a490a259974817b88ce490a74df8d2"
          }
        ]
      },
      .
      .
      .
    ],
    "token": {
      "tenant": {
        "name": "users/lars",
        "id": "28a490a259974817b88ce490a74df8d2",
        "enabled": true,
        "description": null
      },
      "id": "TOKENID",
      "expires": "2014-02-21T20:07:36Z",
      "issued_at": "2014-02-20T20:07:36.189044"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works! Been struggling the whole day, finally found that myself 5 seconds ago after looking into the Keystone source code, but failed to find that in the documentation :(

Comment: A helpful hint, if you weren't already aware: most of the OpenStack command line clients (like the `nova` or `keystone` commands) have a `--debug` flag that will show you exactly what requests they're making.  I've found these examples to be helpful when looking at the API reference.